# Can「他【ほか】に」and「それに」be used interchangeably when conveying "in addition"?

Tags: words, usage, adverbs, synonyms

I am looking for any difference in terms of nuance, usage or frequent collocations so I can tell in what situation I should use one instead of the other.

On the other hand, if the case is that the choice is only a matter of style or personal preference, it would be nice to know as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit hard to explain by definition, but there is certainly a significant difference in usage.

At the start of a sentence, 「それに、」 is used generally like "also, " and "besides, " would. Starting a sentence with 「他に、」 would be appropriate in more specific circumstances, like "other than those, (there is) also (...)".

Within a sentence, それに would be used as in

> 「あの人{ひと}が**それに**関{かか}わっていたという証拠{しょうこ}はない」

I.e. "There is no proof he/she was involved **in that**". On the other hand, in the middle of a sentence, 他に would indeed used as "besides (x)", as pointed out in a comment. E.g.

> 「私達{わたしたち}の他{ほか}に誰{だれ}かいたか？」
>
> "Was there someone else there, besides us?"

whereas

> 「私達{わたしたち}のそれに、誰{だれ}かいたか？」

would mean something like "Was there someone in 'that thing of ours'?", and even then it would be grammatically suspect.

Comment: 「貴方【あなた】の友達【ともだち】の**他【ほか】に**誰【だれ】か来【き】ますか。(Is anyone coming **besides** your friends?). I guess we couldn't say 「貴方【あなた】の友達【ともだち】の**それに**誰【だれ】か来【き】ますか。」, could we? If I understood correctly, 他に is used when adding contrast with an object of the same sentence, while それに is used to add more information or add a while new sentence?